# Integrating Firebase Auth and Identity Platform

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity

Is there a way to combine the benefits of Identity Platform (OIDC and SAML) with Firebase Auth? A project I am working on needs sign in with Apple, which only Firebase auth supports as of right now. It also requires using SAML. Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identity Platform is an upgraded version of Firebase Auth. You can upgrade your Firebase project to an Identity Platform project. Any existing supported Firebase IdP or behavior will continue to work (no changes to your code). You will get the added benefit of SLAs, SAML, OIDC, MFA with SMS and multi-tenancy support among other, but everything should continue to work. However, note that Identity Platform is a [paid service](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing) above a certain number of monthly active users.

Comment: So Sign In with Apple will continue to work despite it not being on identity platform?

Comment: That is correct. Sign in with Apple has not been added to the Identity Platform Cloud Console UI but under the hood it is still supported.

Comment: @bojeil What about pricing ? does Sign in with Apple count on Identity Platform or still under Firebase Auth ? (As there is no backward possibilities after upgrading to Identity Platform)

Comment: As of now, Apple IdP has been added to Identity Platform. It is treated similarly to Facebook, Twitter and other providers. You don't need to upgrade from Firebase to Identity Platform to use it.

Comment: @bojeil I had a question about Identity Platform for Authentication. If I were to add a Phone number as a login option, when I go to configure, it takes me to a Firebase page. Does this mean there are only certain kinds of Providers I can use in Identity Platform that are considered HIPAA compliant?